# Changing text color for setError method for editText fields

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
editTextField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nameText)
editTextField.setError(“error message”)
```

For some reason the error messages come with an unreadable combination of darkish background and black text. The old answers for this question are about a deprecated fromHtml method...

Comment: are you using textInputLayout or simple edittext ? Posting more code will be good to give us the idea what issue exactly you are facing.

Comment: @Umair it’s an editText , added a line to clear the ambiguity

Comment: you know you can change error color and background. Default way of showing error message is above you already wrote. And in material design you use textInputLayout on which the error message is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

**`Try This To Use Html.fromHtml() in all APIs`**:-

```
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
       public static Spanned fromHtml(String html)
       { 
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY); 
        } else{ 
        return Html.fromHtml(html);
       }
```

Just Use It With Flag Parameter
   **`Flag Parameters Are`**:-

```
public static final int FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT = 63;
public static final int FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY = 0;
public static final int FROM_HTML_OPTION_USE_CSS_COLORS = 256;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_BLOCKQUOTE = 32;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_DIV = 16;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_HEADING = 2;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST = 8;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST_ITEM = 4;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_PARAGRAPH = 1;
public static final int TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE = 0;
public static final int TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_INDIVIDUAL = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String errorString = "This field cannot be empty";  // Your custom error message.
    ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(errorColor);
    SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(errorString);
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(foregroundColorSpan, 0, errorString.length(), 0);
    editTextView.setError(spannableStringBuilder);
```